# Keras CNN model accuracy not improving and decreasing over epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Newbie to machine learning here.
I'm currently working on a diagnostic machine learning framework using 3D-CNNs on fMRI imaging. My dataset consists of 636 images right now, and I'm trying to distinguish between control and affected (binary classification). However, when I tried to train my model, after every epoch, my accuracy remains at 48.13%, no matter what I do. Additionally, over the epoch, the accuracy decreases from 56% to 48.13%.
So far, I have tried:

- changing my loss functions (poisson, categorical cross entropy, binary cross entropy, sparse categorical cross entropy, mean squared error, mean absolute error, hinge, hinge squared)
- changing my optimizer (I've tried Adam and SGD)
- changing the number of layers
- using weight regularization
- changing from ReLU to leaky ReLU (I thought perhaps that could help if this was a case of overfitting)

Nothing has worked so far.

Any tips? Here's my code:

```
#importing important packages
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU
import numpy as np
from keras.regularizers import l2
from sklearn.utils import compute_class_weight
from keras.optimizers import SGD

BATCH_SIZE = 64
input_shape=(64, 64, 40, 20)

# Create the model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005), bias_regularizer=l2(0.005), data_format = 'channels_first', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005), bias_regularizer=l2(0.005), data_format = 'channels_first', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))

model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005), bias_regularizer=l2(0.005), data_format = 'channels_first', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005), bias_regularizer=l2(0.005), data_format = 'channels_first', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
 
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.sgd(lr=0.000001), loss='poisson', metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

# Model Testing 
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=50, verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Your learning rate is too small `lr=0.000001`. Try `lr=0.01` , and `lr=0.001`. Having very small learning rate can cause your model not to learn.

Comment: I just tried changing the learning rate - there was no change.

Comment: Softmax with one neuron makes absolutely no sense, if you want to do binary classification you have to use sigmoid at the last layer with one neuron and binary crossentropy loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are using `softmax` activation with 1 neuron. Change it to `sigmoid` with `binary_crossentropy` as a loss function.

At the same time, bear in mind that you are using `Poisson` loss function, which is suitable for regression problems not classification ones. Ensure that you detect the exact scenario that your are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Softmax with one neuron makes the model illogical and only use one of the sigmoid activation functions or Softmax in the last layer